# Can't find the method route in any source code of sinatra

Tags: ruby

I want figure out the connection between the Rack and Sinatra, so I dig into the source code, then I found the the definition of the basic class method `get`:

```
def get(path, opts={}, &block)
  conditions = @conditions.dup
  route('GET', path, opts, &block)

  @conditions = conditions
  route('HEAD', path, opts, &block)
end
```

now what's the method: route? I'm currently using yard document tool, I just can't find the definition of route in any Sinatra code or even Rack code.

Comment: I added some details about how `route` method generally works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't look for the source code very well :) 10 lines below `#get` method definition there is a definition of `route` private method:

```
# lib/sinatra/base.rb, line 1212
private
      def route(verb, path, options={}, &block)
        # Because of self.options.host
        host_name(options.delete(:host)) if options.key?(:host)
        enable :empty_path_info if path == "" and empty_path_info.nil?
        signature = compile!(verb, path, block, options)
        (@routes[verb] ||= []) << signature
        invoke_hook(:route_added, verb, path, block)
        signature
      end
```

This is a private method and you will not find it in the Sinatra documentation.

Generally this method does the following: It create proc from passed `&block`, combine it with http path, keys and invocation conditions (inside `compile!` method) and store it in `@routes[verb]` class instance variable so that block may be found by path and conditions and executed later on (this class also has `attr_reader :routes` defined so that other classes may get acces to its `@routes` instance variable).

Later when you get http request matching this route (`@request` instance variable of `Base` class ) the block is executed inside `Base#route!` method (see line 795).

I would recommend you to use some IDE that help to examin source code. For example I use [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) for this purpose and its feature `Go To -> Declaration`: Just put your cursor on the variable/method/class/etc, press F12 and Rubymine will find it for you, even in source code of connected gems.

Comment: Great answer with great excellent explanation, although I'm not 100% figure it out, but it starts to make sense to me, Happy Spring Festival